# Excel Pivot Table: Can't Create If Statement in Calculated Field

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have created a Pivot Table in Excel.  Here are the fields:

[image]

And here is how it looks:

[image]

What I want to do now is create a calculated field called Stock Price.  The goal of this field is to list the PRICE value IF the Type is 'Stock'.  I.e., PRICE and Type are columns in my data.  I want to create a new column called Stock Price and populate that with data ONLY if the Type equals Stock.

I thought I could do using an if formula as follows:  `IF(type="Stock",PRICE,0)`

[image]

However, the result is NOT what I expected.  This is what I get:

[image]

All of the rows have a value of 0, even when the Type equals Stock.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Moshe Try with sum with condition or sumproduct with conditions (you have just one)